# mySQL query with join and multiple unions

Tags: mysql

I have this query that joins two tables where a condition is met:

```
SELECT * FROM order
JOIN reservations
ON order.reservationsID=reservations.ID
WHERE posname='Fixed'
```

From this result I need to filter down to certain date ranges from the reservations table. If I were to query the reservations table (has year, month, block columns) alone I would have the following query:

```
(SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE YEAR=2016 AND MONTH=11 AND BLOCK>1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE YEAR=2016 AND MONTH>11)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM reservations 
WHERE YEAR>2016)
```

How can I merge these two queries into one? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word in MySQL - so you're not quite telling us the whole truth ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
SELECT * FROM [order]
JOIN reservations ON [order].reservationsID=reservations.ID
WHERE posname='Fixed' AND ( (YEAR=2016 AND MONTH=11 AND BLOCK>1) OR
                            (YEAR=2016 AND MONTH>11) OR
                            (YEAR>2016) )
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be working well. I think I was trying to make it more difficult than it needed to be.